# JAX-WS wsdl in cluster environment

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

I'm encountering a bit of a problem when I deploy my web-services application on a cluster.

The wsld is published and can be accessed using the [urlofcluster]/[webapp]/manageparticipantidentifier?wsdl url.

But when I take a look inside i see this:

```
<s:import namespace="http://busdox.org/serviceMetadata/locator/1.0/" schemaLocation="http://[ipaddress]/[webapp]/manageparticipantidentifier?xsd=2"/>
```

Since this cluster is behind a firewall, the machine is not accessible trough the ip from the world-wide web...

so the question is... How can i make Jax-ws replace the ip-address by the url of the cluster in the wsdl's ?

For now this app needs to be deployed on weblogic, but other platforms need to be possible 2...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tomcat/JBoss servers allow to specify a proxyHostname/proxyPort which are used as the external hostname/port. http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/proxy-howto.html.

There is some doc for the topic, look here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/cluster/setup.html

Comment: I've read your suggestions mp911de, but I'm wondering if anyone can clearify my view on this, which rules are followed by JAX-WS for the creation of the links inside the wsdl's ?

Comment: This depends pretty much on the stack you use (CXF, Metro Stack). You can provide for example a static WSDL and only the environmental parts (hostname) are replaced. JBossAS 7/Wildfly 8 has explicit settings on what should happen on WSDL creation.

Comment: Currently we are using the tomcat and websphere as supported environments. The Wsdl is supplied in the war on the path WEB-INF/wsdl however not accessible on that path only trough webapp/servisename?wsdl
JAX-ws somehow processes this file by making xsd-paths fixed etc...